# RoR bundle get '=1.0.3 java' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jdbc, bundle

I'm using JRuby and need to get specific version of a gem:

```
C:\>gem list activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter --remote --all

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter (1.2.6, 1.2.5, 1.2.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.3, 1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.3 java, 1.0.2 java, 1.0.1 java, 1.0.0 java, 0.9.7
java, 0.9.6 java, 0.9.5 java, 0.9.4 java, 0.9.3 java, 0.9.2, 0.9.1, 0.9.0.1, 0.9, 0.8.2, 0.8.1)
```

Ok, so I put this in Gemfile:

```
gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter', '=1.0.3 java'
```

But bundle doesn't undestand that:

```
C:\bundle install
c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/requirement.rb:81:in `parse': Illformed requirement ["=1.0.3 java"] (ArgumentError)
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/requirement.rb:106:in `initialize'
       org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2379:in `map!'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/requirement.rb:106:in `initialize'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/requirement.rb:44:in
`create'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:50:in `initialize'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/dependency.rb:28:in `initialize'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:72:in `gem'
       C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/test_jdbc_rails_sqlite/Gemfile:9:in `(eval)'
       org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2086:in `instance_eval'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:32:in `eval_gemfile'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `evaluate'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:18:in `build'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:144:in `definition'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:228:in `install'
       org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2105:in `send'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:408:in `start'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/bin/bundle:14:in `(root)'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:4:in `with_friendly_errors'
       c:/soft/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/bin/bundle:14:in `(root)'
       org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1087:in `load'
       c:\soft\jruby-1.6.8\bin\bundle:23:in `(root)'
There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried leaving out 'java': `gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter', '1.0.3'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter', '=1.0.3', :platforms => :jruby
```

But if you're using jruby you probably don't need the platfrom part.